# How to extend a list of HTML elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, list

There is a method `push` which allows to extend a list with elements unpacked from another list. I checked it with a couple of simple lists of numbers to make sure my browser supports it. It does.

Here I'm trying to do the same for a list of `HTML` elements, but `buttons.push is not a function`.

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.push(...document.querySelectorAll("input[type = 'submit']"));
```

I've surfed the web, and every source I saw claimed that `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `list`. Therefore, the method must work. Why does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a [node list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which doesn't seem to have a `push` method.

[JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) have push, and you can convert a node list to an array via `[...nodeList]`

You could convert between the two like so:

```
var buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')];
buttons.push(...document.querySelectorAll("input[type = 'submit']"));
```

Comment: Is there an alternative for a `node list`? Sth like `push`?

Comment: The common way to represent a list of items is an array, so the traditional alternative to a node list is an array. Is there a case where an array doesn't work for you?